# CORS for static HTML in vNext

Tags: cors, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC6 site running in Visual Studio 2015 RC

I've got some static HTML files I want to serve to another website.  I want to add CORS support (without having to add a controller and add CORS that way).

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Startup.cs

Configure the policy in ConfigureServices ...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowEverything", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
            });
    }
```

Then in Configure set the app to use the policy, then set UseStaticFiles ...

Ensure that UseStaticFiles() comes after UseCors - at least in the version I'm using (installed with Visual Studio 2015 RC) it needs to come after UseCors()

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowEverything");
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.  When I posted the question I was thinking there must be some special of assigning a CORS policy to static files, but it was just the order of the code that was throwing things off.

Comment: Important fact for me was having the UseStaticFiles AFTER UseCors. That wasn't clear in the official documentation (as of today):  http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html

Comment: Is it necessary to add AllowCredentials ? I have app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            }); it works for dynamic contents but doesn't work for static files. Any help would be highly appreciated :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow the server to accept CORS.

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Client(browser) must know that server accepts the CORS because browser checks for the Allow Cors in the response of server, if it's allowed or not and then it allows displaying data even if it's static content like plain HTML.